# Clio API V4 Communication how to add Time Entry VIA API?

Tags: clio-api

I'm just wondering if there is a way to add a Recorded Time in Communication Phone Call using the API?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just found it in the documentation Activity Endpoint.

https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#operation/Activity#create

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you managed to answer your own question, but for anyone dealing with the same or similar issue, I thought I would throw in my two cents.

This is really a two step operation:

1. Create the Communication log through a POST request to /api/v4/communications.json endpoint.
2. Create an activities entry associated with the communication you just created through a POST request to /api/v4/activites.json.

After you create the communication, you can get the ID back for the record you just made.  Using that, you create a new Activity record, and as part of the payload, you include the ID in the following.

```
{
"data": {
    "communication": {
        "id": 0
    },
    "quantity": $time_qty,
    "date": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "type": "TimeEntry"
    }
}
```